# Find maximal matching in tree in $O\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)$

Tags: graphs, matching, binary

As any tree can be described as a binary sequence ($i$-th bit is 0 if the edge goes down and 1 otherwise, every edge is travelled twice $-$ up and down, so such sequence's length is $2 |V| - 2$), any tree of size $n$ can be encoded as $O\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)$ integers (assuming an integer holds $\log n$ bits in our model).

The task is to find maximal matching in a tree given in a described form in $O\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)$ time (thus, linear in the integer count).

I was wondering if any simple solution exists, as for trees I can find maximal matching in $O\left(n\right)$ time using simple dynamic programming approach.

Comment: It sounds like you got this challenge from somewhere.  Can you cite/credit the original source of this?  Does it have any clues why it suggests that this is possible in $O(n / \log n)$ time?  Also, can you specify the model of computation more carefully?  When we care about the difference between $O(n)$ and $O(n / \log n)$ time, the exact model of computation can matter a lot.

Comment: Can you state more clearly how you encode the tree?  What do you mean by an edge going "down"?  What does each integer represent?  What is the sequence you are referring to?  Is it an in-order traversal of the tree?